# How to avoid */* mime types in Intent filters

Tags: android, mime-types

## AndroidDev

I have an Intent filter that accepts images :

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But if I select images and a movie then filter still gets trapped even though the mimetype is "*/*"

Is there something that I can do so that my application is not called for "*/*"?  Of course I can deal with it after my app is launched but that just seems ridiculous to me. I would rather my app not be in the share list.

Comment: Do you really handle any time of image? If not why not just specify 'image/png', etc for every type you actually handle?

Comment: I'm using UIL @chwiz, I'm not sure exactly which types it handles. However, I don't think that would change anything here.

Comment: I thought that perhaps if you declared no wildcards android would be a little more strict. Just speculation though.

Comment: I was actually getting ready to try and approach like this @schwiz but now I don't think it will work.  I think that if I explicitly declare "image/png" + "image/jpg" and then the user tries to pass a .png AND a .jpg that it won't work because the type will be "image/*" which I don't support...  sigh.

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev Did you manage to solve this problem? In my application I support images & presentations, but not together. The problem is when a user selects an image & a presentation then it is passed as "*/*" which I don't want to allow..

Comment: Sorry, I  did not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i dont think there is a way to do that. If you need to be able to have an image and a movie at the same time you are going to need the */*. If you only want multiple images OR multiple movies, then you might be able to setup 2 different intent-filters, one for images and one for movies.

Comment: It's actually an error case, I don't want movies but my app can still be called with them.

Comment: Why dont you check the type programmatically and ignore the movie files?

Comment: Because it's a bad UX for me to allow movies to be shared to my app and then not display them.  I would prefer for my app not to show up in the share choices.